# ComboBox SelectedItem throws exception in Windows 10

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-10

following code works fine under Windows 8.1
and I recently upgraded my OS to Windows 10 and it throws an exception.

Here is a screenshot of the exception
[image]

This is the XAML code:

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      TabIndex="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DateFormats}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding DateFormatSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

When I removed the part "SelectedItem" it works but I need the SelectedItem
to be displayed.
Please help.

Here the event viewer application error details. It doesn't provide much info either

> Faulting application name: BoardPACWinApp.exe, version: 0.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x55bdb705
>   Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16397, time stamp: 0x55af0da4
>   Exception code: 0xc000027b
>   Fault offset: 0x00722f90
>   Faulting process id: 0x1e48
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d0cd2970f53bb1
>   Faulting application path: D:\Projects\BoardPACWinApp\BoardPACWinApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\BoardPACWinApp.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
>   Report Id: 38e21b5c-cf75-4849-81df-01bb412c291a
>   Faulting package full name: IronOneTechnologiesPvtLtd.BoardPACWinDemo_3.14.35.2_x86__na7z394ep8t7e
>   Faulting package-relative application ID: App

Comment: The screenshot is not quite helpful. If you run in release mode without using Visual Studio, after the crash, can you get some useful information of the exception from Event Viewer?

Comment: I've updated the question, unfortunately it doesn't give much information regarding the error.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar exception and it was caused because I was manipulating the ItemsSource binding property (List<>) when the binding process started. Now I make all the manipulations on a temp collection which I assign to the binded property when all manipulations to the collection are finished.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Nop, do you see my answer below, there was a issue with Win 10 that prevent the binding somehow. By using the code instead of XAML solved the case.

Comment: I'm agree that there is something wrong with Win10 binding. I overcome this issue generating first the viewmodel collection property binded to the ItemsSource property of the ComboBox and not manipulating directly this collection, and after that I assign the viewmodel property which is binded with the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox (this is important too, if I assign first the property binded to the SelectedItem property i get the exception). With this workarround I don't break the MVVM pattern like you do with your solution. In my case it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is do the `SelectedItem` binding using the code view.

Here's my XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="DateFormatsComboBox" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource CustomBlueComboBoxStyle}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DateFormats}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomBlueComboBoxItemStyle}">
            <!--NOTE: Removed coz Windows 10 had issues | 2015-08-16 | SurenM -->
            <!--SelectedItem="{Binding DateFormatSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"-->
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Here's my C# code:

```
//NOTE: Windows 10 had issues with XAML Combobox SelectItem, so it was brought to code behind
            DateFormatsComboBox.SelectedItem = _model.DateFormatSelected;
```

NOTE: _model.DateFormatSelected is a `CustomKeyValuePair<string, string>`

This approach is tested on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 both and it works great.